# MDS excel add in issue while selecting values in domain based attribute

Tags: drop-down-menu, excel-2010, excel-addins, master-data-services, master-data-management

When I am trying to select a value in domain based attribute using MDS Excel Add in, I am getting a long list of BLANK values in the dropdown. These blank records does not exist in my MDS database. Wondering from where these records are coming in the dropdown menu. Is this some kind of issue in MDS excel add in? Has anyone encountered the same problem and found a solution/Workaround, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved now. Blank records from the drop down menu were gone when I refreshed the data in the excel using 'Refresh' button in Master data tab. This thing didn't strike earlier. But that's the resolution to this problem! :)